# Showing number of entries needed in antd table in react JS

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using antd Table(https://ant.design/components/table/) in my react project. I want to show the number of entries for the table like the below picture.

[image]

I am importing `Table` from `antd`
Then using this code

```
<Table
                    className="table-layout"
                    columns={this.state.columns}
                    dataSource={filteredData} 
                    bordered={true}
                    size={"small"}
                    onRowDoubleClick={ (record, index, event) => this.handleEditModal(record) }
                    onRowClick={(record, index, event) => this.handleRowClick(record)}
                    loading={this.state.loading}
                    pagination={{ pageSize: 14 }}  
                    rowClassName={(record) => this.state.selectedItemKey == record.key ? 'table-layout selected' :  record.IsDefaultAccount ? 'table-layout active' : 'table-layout' }                 
                />
```

Is is possible in antd table? If so how to do it?

Comment: please post your code

Comment: I have updated the question with code @ Just code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: the screen shot for the sandbox you shared]

You can use antd pagination component and can achieve your need like mentioned below

```
import { Pagination } from 'antd'; 
<Pagination size="small" total={50} showSizeChanger />
```

and can refer to antd pagination demo and documentation at [this link](https://ant.design/components/pagination/#components-pagination-demo-mini)

Comment: When I opened the sandbox of the above link, only Pagination is showing.
The  option for sizeChanger is not working

Comment: can you share the link to sandbox that you opened

Comment: I am able see  sizeChanger in the sandbox you shared updated my answer with the screen shot

Comment: Okay it worked . Wasn't able to see it because of screen size. Thank you  Sumanth Madishetty

Comment: Happy to help @JaneFred